# How to control the sort order of mapper result in mapreduce before being sent to reducer

Tags: sorting, hadoop, mapreduce, shuffle

Taking a slight variation of the word count example to explain what I am trying to do.

I have 3 mappers each producing a complete word count result on 3 large input files. 
Let us say the output is:

```
Mapper 1 Result:
-------
cat 100
dog 50
fox 10

Mapper 2 Result:
-------
fox 200
pig 5
rat 1

Mapper 3 Result:
-------
dog 70
rat 50
fox 10
```

Notice that each result is a complete word count with unique key,count results for given files.

Now on the reducer side my algorithm requires that there be only one reducer, 
and for reasons that are a bit too lengthy to discuss here, I want the results from each mapper to be fed into reducer in the descending order of counts but without performing any shuffle and sort step. i.e. I like the reducer to receive the results from each mapper in the following order without any grouping by key:

```
cat 100
dog 50
fox 10

fox 200
pig 5
rat 1

dog 70
rat 50
fox 10
```

i.e. just load the results of each mapper into reducer in the descending order of value(not key)

Comment: To clarify, normal behavior would be that for `dog` what would be sent to the Reducer would be '("dog", {50,70})`. Do you want it sent to the Reducer as `("dog", {70,50})`? Or do you not want common keys produced by disparate `Mappers` to be combined?

Comment: Hi john, you are right, I do not want common keys produced by disparate Mappers to be combined. Also at the same time I want the single reducer to receive tuples from all mappers in the descending oder of counts because the algorithm involves finding the topN elements..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this should be a Map-only job since you don't want Shuffle and Sort to happen.

If you REALLY need to use Reduce then I suggest you need to have a composite key and do secondary sort.

The key would include a mapper id, normal key and the count value. You would do primary sort on mapper id and secondary sort on count. You would also need a grouping comparator that did not group anything (or grouped on mapper id and normal key only).

Again, looking at all the stuff you would need to do to use a Reducer just to prevent Shuffle and Sort, seems like this should be a Map-only job unless the output must be in a single file.

Comment: and even if it has to be a single file he can always use the -getmerge shell command... http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.19.1/hdfs_shell.html#getmerge

Comment: Thanks for your response..good to know that it is actually possible.. I think I do need a reducer because the idea is that each of these mapper results represents a "partial" TopN result of an approximation algorithm that is executed using a combiner..  now these partial topN results have to be merged using the same algorithm to produce global approximate TopN. (Very similar to what the CountBy does in Cascading).. also -getmerge is not an option since this is not a simple merge..